# What SQL injections can bypass this authentication page?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I am working on building a login page to demonstrate SQL injections. I've tried my best to build the most "simple" login. I've been using credentials such as `1' or '1' = '1` for username & password, and getting the "nay" message when logging in, meaning it just recognizes it as incorrect user & pass. I have also tried logging in with `1' or '1' = '1'))/*` as username and `foo` as password, and getting a 500 Server error when logging in.

- Am I implementing the SQL injections incorrectly?
- Do I need to "dummy" down the login implementation?

Where I got the SQL injection testing: https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/05-Testing_for_SQL_Injection

Here is my authentication page:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {
echo "yay";
} else {
echo "nay";
}
?>
```

My issue might be that I am trying to take the inputted username & password and compare to the data stored in my db, which is why it's just recognizing the injections as incorrect usernames & passwords.

Comment: This is not a security issue. You need to debug your code. This is a pure programming issue. Start by figuring out what's working and what's not. For instance, return the count to see how many are getting returned ...

Answer (score 5):

Your code is checking `if($count == 1)`. This means that authentication will only be successful if the SQL query returns exactly 1 record. The problem with the simple `1' OR '1'='1'` in this case is that it matches every record in the table, so it returns all of them. Using that payload, injection will be successful if and only if the table contains exactly one record. Try using `1' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1; --`  instead to limit the number of rows returned to one.